# Dictionaries in Django Views: Iterating over a dictionary containing key-queryset pairs

Tags: django, dictionary, refactoring, django-queryset, detailview

Currently, I have a very bloated detail view function in my Django Views module.  The main reason for this is because I'm creating lists from dictionaries (between 2-50 key-value pairs) by iterating over each dictionary and appending the result to a unique list.  These lists are then made available to the templates for further iteration and display.
Here is an example of a list from dictionary code within the detail view function in Views:

```
def bacteria_detail_view(request, slug):
...
   temperature = []
   temp_dict = {'low': My_model.growth_temp_low, 'room_temp': My_model.growth_temp_room, 
   'body_temp': My_model.growth_temp_body, 'high': My_model.growth_temp_high}
   for key, val in temp_dict.items():
      if val is not None:
         temperature.append(val)
...
```

This is then displayed in the template:

```
<li>
    {% if temperature %}
    <i style="color: blue"><b>T</b>emperature tolerance:</i>
    {% for t in temperature %}
    {{ t|growstemp|default_if_none:''}}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</li>
```

A custom template filter is applied to the iterated object:

```
@register.filter(name='growstemp')
def growstemp(value):
    if value:
        if "+" in value:
            value = value.replace("(+)", "")
            return f"grows at {value}\u2103;"
        elif "neg" in value:
            value = value.replace("(neg)", "")
            return f"doesn't grow at {value}\u2103;"
    ...
    else:
        return ''
```

This approach works well, but I suspect it is not optimal and it does crowd the View function.  Is there a more straight-forward approach?  Because the dictionaries are key-QuerySet pairs, is there a better way, such as accessing a Model 'verbose name': 'field name' key-value pair programmatically? Or is there a way of refactoring the dictionaries and removing them from the View module?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of what these attributes contain and what your model looks like? When you say between 2-50 key-value pairs do you mean that you construct a dictionary with 50 keys from 50 different attributes on an instance?

Comment: Hi Iain, I have a model with more than 700 fields.  This is because I have >1300 bacteria, which all have ~700 attributes (so the matrix is roughly 1300*700 possible data points).  Each dictionary described above is a subset of related field names; the "temp_dict" dictionary contains only 4 such key/value pairs.  Am I approaching this incorrectly?  Should I break the model up into dozens of models and use foreign keys or many_to_many fields?  Cheers.